# Use of Exponential Integral in solving an integral

Tags: integration, exponential-function

If I'm solving a version of the following integral

$\int \log(x)e^x dx$

how does the exponential integral arise as a solution to this?  (Or is it much too theoretical to explain simply?)  I do a much more complicated version of this on WolframAlpha.com and the Ei(x) function is used, but it is used with the above integral too, and no steps are given.

I understand the form of Ei(x), but thought that someone might be able to explain how it arises as a solution to the above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using integration by parts 
\begin{equation}\int \log(x)e^x dx=\int \log(x)(e^x)^{\prime} dx=\log(x)e^x -\int (\log(x))^{\prime}e^x dx=\log(x)e^x -\int \frac{e^x}{x} dx\end{equation}
The last integral is the exponential integral $Ei(x)$

Comment: Oh, very nice!  I love it when things are simple.  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

$\int\log{x}\ e^x dx=\log{x}\ e^x - \int\frac{e^x}{x}dx $ - integration by parts